# Date Manipulations in R

Tags: r, date, max, min

I have a dataframe as below, I need to find the number of days are within the scope ( which spans between the start dt and end dt ) The logic is as per the applicable_days formula below.

```
cust start-dt    end-dt      item item_type  year applicable_days
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx  2019 MIN("2019-12-31", end-dt) - MAX(start-dt,"2019-01-01") 
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx  2020 MIN("2020-12-31", end-dt) - MAX(start-dt,"2020-01-01")
```

I tried multiple ways of doing it. It is not working. Can you someone help me where I am making a mistake?

Trial 1:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    applicable-days =  (min( as.Date(paste0(year,"-12-31")), end-dt) - max(start-dt, as.Date(paste0(year,"-01-01"))) )
  )
```

Outcome -> gives the same value as the first record.

Trial 2:

```
df[,"applicable-days"] <- as.numeric(min( as.Date(paste0(df[,"year"],"-12-31")) , df[,"end-dt"] ) - 
                                     max( df[,"start-dt"] , as.Date(paste0(df[,"year"],"-01-01"))) )
```

Outcome -> returns only NA

Trial 3 :

```
df[,"applicable-days"] <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
                               as.numeric(min( as.Date(paste0(x["year"],"-12-31")) , x["end-dt"] ) - 
                                          max( x["start-dt"] , as.Date(paste0(x["year"],"-01-01"))) )
                                })
```

Outcome -> returns only NA

When i try it using just one value it works fine for the last 2 trials.

Please help me spot the mistake here.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you share data with `dput(head(df,n))`?

Comment: check your `start-dt` `end-dt` are also `date` class

Comment: @FrankZhang, Ya I ensured they are date class. I even added "origin" value to the as.Date function. Yet no luck

Comment: @NelsonGon Please find the structure . I masked the columns that are not relevant to the case . structure(list(CUST = structure(1L, .Label = "XXXX", class = "factor"), 
    START_DT = structure(17789, class = "Date"), END_DT = structure(18885, class = "Date"), 
    TRANS_DT = structure(17975, class = "Date")), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

Comment: `apply` on a data frame is bad because it first coerces things to a `matrix`, which converts everything to the same class.

Comment: @SruthySivakumar I have run your code using the data structure provided by you in comments, added year manually as it was not present. Below is working fine for me:   `df$year<-"2018"
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    a=min(as.Date(paste0(year,"-12-31")), END_DT),
    b=max(START_DT, as.Date(paste0(year,"-01-01"))),
    applicable_days =  a-b
  )`